# How can I speed up this update and set?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, x and y

I have created a query that updates x.col_p with the sum of column y.col_p where they both match a particular date and ID.

```
UPDATE x 
SET col_p = (
    SELECT sum(col_p) 
    FROM y 
    WHERE concat(x.mmonth, x.dday, x.yyear) = (concat(y.mmonth, y.dday, y.yyear))
        AND x.ID = y.ID
    )
```

This successfully updates the colums with the correct values but it takes 15 minutes to execute and I have ~40 more similar queries to run like this... So how could I go about speeding this up? I think the functions inside the set and where are killing me.

Comment: Have you tried using [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-explain.html) and `ANALYZE` to check what the execution plan for the query is? Generally look out for whole table scans that might not be using indexes.

Comment: You should not split dates into separate {day,month,year} columns. Instead, use a single DATE column type. BTW: concatenation will probably cause '12/1/2017' and `1/21/2017` to compare as equal, which they are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
UPDATE x 
    SET col_p = (SELECT sum(col_p) 
                 FROM y 
                 WHERE x.yyear = y.yyear AND x.mmonth = y.mmonth AND
                       x.dday = y.dday AND x.ID = y.ID
                );
```

Then be sure that you have an index on `y(ID, yyear, mmonth, dday, col_p)`.

Comment: This works very well my query went from taking 15 minutes to finishing in 9 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The things you can do are:

1. Assure the table `y`is reached by a primary key (of which column `y.id` is the first column).
2. If you don't have any null columns, it seems you may not need `concat`. That is why rather than `concat(x.mmonth, x.dday, x.yyear) = (concat(y.mmonth, y.dday, y.yyear))`, try `(x.mmonth, x.dday, x.yyear) = (y.mmonth, y.dday, y.yyear)`.
3. After you are sure, `y` uses a proper primary key, you can make the `update` by giving a parallel hint to `x`. For example, in order to use 4 parallel processes, `update /*+ PARALLEL(x 4) */ x ...` For this step be careful to use system resources properly.

So to wrap the things up, what I am suggesting is;

- reach to the table you go "a lot of times", i.e. table `y` via primary key
- reach to the table you make full scan, i.e. table `x` via parallel processes.